# Triggering Click Event after a particular click event.(Bind-function)

Tags: javascript, jquery, bind, unbind

Below is my html and jquery. Thorugh jquery i am adding and remove  class-disBloS to the div named inn by toggleClass funciton when logBtn is clicked.
Also i made a funciton to remove the disBloS form the Div(inn) when the user clicks any were on the page. but the problem is that function triggers every time when i click  any were in the body. My need is It has to trigger only when the logBtn Button is clicked before that. it dosent has to trigger when the logBtn Button is not clicked Before

### Html Code

```
<a href="#" class="togg" id="logBtn"></a>
<div class="inn"></div>
```

### Jquery to add disBloS when clicked logBtn

```
$('#logBtn').click(function() {
    arrNext = $(this).next();
    arrow = $(this);
    $(this).next().toggleClass('disBloS');
    $(this).toggleClass('up');
});
```

### Jquery to remove disBloS when clicked any were on page

```
$('body').click(function(e){
  if(e.target.id !== 'logBtn') {
          $(arrNext).removeClass('disBloS');
          $(arrow).removeClass('up');

  }
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Does this solve your problem ?
This will stop the click on logBtn from propagating to the body.

```
$('#logBtn').click(function(e){
    $(this).next().toggleClass('disBloS');
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```